# How to do auto convert for php date format?

Tags: php, strtotime

I have recently got a PHP coding for a simple calender pickup. But it is in date format of mm/dd/yy. Is there anyway that I can auto convert it to yy-mm-dd? I heard using strtotime can change it automatically when it enters the database but I do not know how and where to add the code to. I try adding like.. `strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($Date))` in the main page but I do not know where to add this but all the places are not valid. Any help to offer? Help is greatly appreciated.

This is roughly how it looks like in my main page:

```
if(isset($_POST["insert_click"]))
{
    $Date=$_POST["Date"];
    strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($Date)); //I tried putting it here but it does not work
    $Time=$_POST["Time"];
    $query=$connect->prepare("insert into Booking(Date, Time) values (?,?)");
    $query->bind_param('ss', $Date, $Time);
    $query->execute();
}
```

This is roughly how it looks in my form page:

```
<tr>
<td>Date:</td>
<td>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function()
    {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate:0});
        $( "#format" ).change(function()
        {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30" name="Date"/>

</body>
</html>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($Date));` is correct. You have only forgotten to assign the return value of this function to a variable. You will want something like this:

```
$newDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($Date));
```

If you don't need the original date anymore, you can also do:

```
$Date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($Date));
```

**Note:** These days, you can be pretty lazy when it comes to PHP time formats for use in database or HTML's `<time datetime="bla"></time>` tag. Both the "normal" and localized time formats give you a shortcut to generate commonly used time value combinations, examples are:

1. `c` for [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
2. `%F` for [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: Quoting @jh314 here: "Also, since you want yy-mm-dd, use `%y` instead of `%Y`."

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! X millions times! Thanks thanks! I have managed to do it! Thanks! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to save the results of the date conversion to a variable.  This statement:

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($Date));
```

will do the date conversion and return the converted date, but will leave `$Date` alone.

To fix this, you need to caputure the results by storing the results to a variable:

```
$Date = strftime("%y-%m-%d", strtotime($Date));
```

Also, since you want yy-mm-dd, use `%y` instead of `%Y`.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use the native date-function like this:

```
$Date=DATE('y-m-d, strtotime($_POST["Date"]));
```

Comment: Hi! It is able to convert the date format from mm/dd/yy to yy/mm/dd but the data returned is 1970/01/01. I selected the a date from the datepicker which was 07/26/2013 but it returned me 1970/01/01. What should I do?

Comment: @stupidgal - you could convert the posted date with strtotime(). See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)